# SecurityConfig [Spring boot version 2.5.x]: add filter for ServerHttpSecurity only for secured urls

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to add a filter for ServerHttpSecurity and I want to skip filter for URLs from white list, but filter works for everything, how to avoid that

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            ...
    };

    @Autowired
    private JsonWebTokenParser<Claims> jwtParser;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(jwtParser);

        http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean you don't want to run through the filter for the whitelisted path?

Make 2 Beans where one handles your whitelist and the other for security and add a securityMatcher.

Kotlin example but same applies to Java

```
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    fun whitelistWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
            .securityMatcher(pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST))
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .and().build()
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    fun otherWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
            .securityMatcher(pathMatchers(/*set whatever you need here*/))
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(/*set whatever you need here (same as above)*/).authenticated()
            .and().cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
            .build()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but right now I receive 401 for each request, but from logs, I can see that everything is okay. The filter is working as expected without any errors.